# Fast replacement for off-diagonal blocks in sparse matrix

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse quadratic diagonal matrix `H` of dimension `(K*M) x (K*M)`. The goal is to replace the lower off-diagonal **blocks** of the matrix with a known quadratic matrix `A` with size `K x K`:

```
# dimensions of the final matrix are (K*M) x (K*M)
K        = 5
M        = 3

# initiate the matrix as diagonal
H        = Matrix::Diagonal(K*M)

# convert because off-diagonal replacement does not work for sparse diagonal class
H        = as(H, "dgCMatrix")

# matrix that will replace the lower off-diagonal blocks of size K x K
A        = matrix(runif(K^2), K, K)
```

The following method uses an auxiliary vector that indexes the off-diagonal blocks of appropriate size and loops over each block:

```
# construct vector that is used to index the lower off-diagonal blocks of size K x K
indices   = seq(1, K * (1 + M), K)

# replace all M - 1 lower off-diagonal blocks
for(ii in 1:(M-1)){
  
  H[indices[ii + 1]:(indices[ii + 2]-1), indices[ii]:(indices[ii + 1]-1)] = A

}
```

Unfortunately, indexing and replacing these blocks becomes extremely slow when the dimensionality of the matrix grows. Are there faster methods available that would work reasonably well in settings with, say, `K=8000` and `M=20` ? It does not necessarily need to be within the `Matrix` package setting as long as the result can be back-converted to a `Matrix` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kronecker product of a sparse banded matrix and the dense block should be "fast", but you'll want to do your own benchmarks ...

```r
library(Matrix)
set.seed(0)
K <- 5L
M <- 3L

(X <- bandSparse(M, M, -1L, list(rep.int(1, M - 1L))))
## 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"
##           
## [1,] . . .
## [2,] 1 . .
## [3,] . 1 .

(Y <- matrix(round(runif(K * K), 2L), K, K))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,] 0.90 0.20 0.06 0.77 0.78
## [2,] 0.27 0.90 0.21 0.50 0.93
## [3,] 0.37 0.94 0.18 0.72 0.21
## [4,] 0.57 0.66 0.69 0.99 0.65
## [5,] 0.91 0.63 0.38 0.38 0.13

XY <- kronecker(X, Y)
diag(XY) <- 1
XY
## 15 x 15 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##                                                                  
##  [1,] 1.00 .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    . . . . .
##  [2,] .    1.00 .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    . . . . .
##  [3,] .    .    1.00 .    .    .    .    .    .    .    . . . . .
##  [4,] .    .    .    1.00 .    .    .    .    .    .    . . . . .
##  [5,] .    .    .    .    1.00 .    .    .    .    .    . . . . .
##  [6,] 0.90 0.20 0.06 0.77 0.78 1.00 .    .    .    .    . . . . .
##  [7,] 0.27 0.90 0.21 0.50 0.93 .    1.00 .    .    .    . . . . .
##  [8,] 0.37 0.94 0.18 0.72 0.21 .    .    1.00 .    .    . . . . .
##  [9,] 0.57 0.66 0.69 0.99 0.65 .    .    .    1.00 .    . . . . .
## [10,] 0.91 0.63 0.38 0.38 0.13 .    .    .    .    1.00 . . . . .
## [11,] .    .    .    .    .    0.90 0.20 0.06 0.77 0.78 1 . . . .
## [12,] .    .    .    .    .    0.27 0.90 0.21 0.50 0.93 . 1 . . .
## [13,] .    .    .    .    .    0.37 0.94 0.18 0.72 0.21 . . 1 . .
## [14,] .    .    .    .    .    0.57 0.66 0.69 0.99 0.65 . . . 1 .
## [15,] .    .    .    .    .    0.91 0.63 0.38 0.38 0.13 . . . . 1
```